# Turn on a circuit only when current reaches 500mA

Tags: voltage-regulator

I'm using small solar panels for charging mobile phones.
I have two panels; each deliver approx. 19V 300mA. I used voltage regulators to each to get exactly 5V. Then they're connected in parallel.

So, I have a power supply with 5 volts and amperage varying from 10mA to 950mA.
And I want the power supply to provide the output only if it reaches atleast 500mA. Is there any device or circuit to turn on a circuit only if it reaches certain current?
Thanks in advance...

Comment: "_Is there any device or circuit to turn on a circuit only if it reaches certain current?_" How would it reach any current if it's turned off? Do you see the fundamental problem with your question.

Comment: Probably the easiest way to do what you want is to connect the 5V output to a dummy load with a resistance equal to the real load's, measure the current through the dummy load and then switch (break before make) in the real load when the current through the dummy load gets to exceeds 500mA.

Comment: Apart from the issue with your question, your plan has general issues.   Using a linear regulator to drop to 5V will waste more power as heat than it uses, so you would need a switching regulator.  Generally you should not connect the output of regulators in parallel, but that is especially to be avoided with switching regulators, at least those not designed for such usage.

Answer (score 2):

Obviously it can't reach 500 mA if it hasn't been turned on yet.  Apparently what you are asking is how to know that it *can* produce 500 mA.

Since the input is solar panels, you could measure the insolation or the output of the panels to detect the point you previously determined can sustain 500 mA out of your supply.  You should be able to know the input voltages and currents for the supply to produce 500 mA out.  You could track the solar panel maximum output, dumping the power meanwhile, until it exceeds what is required.

However, that way you'll have to get rid of over 2.5 Watts of heat.  A better way would be to run the solar panel with a fixed resistance.  This resistance loads the panel enough so that you only have to look at the voltage to know what it can do (from previous experimentation) under full load.  However, the power drawn from the panel would be only a few 100 mW maybe, so it causes no extra problem in getting rid of heat.

Answer (score 1):

Adding to what Olin says:

A panel on or near short-circuit will provide a current typically 5% to 10% more than at the maximum power point. The exact ratio can be checked by experiment.
Load the panel with say 2 Ohms so that at 500 MA the voltage across the resistor will be V = I x R = 0.5 x 2 = 1 Volt. Compare this voltage with an adjustable threshold value and switch the panel to the load when current is high enough.

Once the phone is charging you need to decide when to stop charging. Stopping when I chg falls to less than 500 mA will occur not only when solar insolation drops but also at some stage after the battery/charger go into constant voltage mode and current drops progressively. So, you need to have a good understanding of what you want to do and how the battery behaves.